# Excel refer table cells by column name instead of offset

Tags: excel, vba

Please consider the below code, it's iterating over "Country" column of the table and changing the cell 2 positions to it's right to "Changed". I need to stop using the offset and refer to the two columns to right by it's header name "Capital". How to do it?

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
For each lookupcell in lookupsheet.Range("A1:A10")

For Each updatecell in updatesheet.Listobjects(1).Listcolumns("Country").databodyRange

if updatecell.offset(0,2).value= lookupcell.Value 'Need to change this line, remove offset and use column name instead

if updatecell.offset(0,3).value= lookupcell.offset(0,2).Value 'Need to change this line, remove offset from Cell1 and use column name instead

Then.....

Next updatecell

Next lookupcell`
```

Comment: Why are you looping? Why not just `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Capital").DataBodyRange.Value = "Changed"
`?

Comment: Is this all of your code? If there's more logic please update your question to include it

Comment: Hi Jos, Actually I am using the databodyrange of "Country" to update many columns of the table and with different values coming from a separate file, currently using offset but I fear the column locations might change hence trying to refer by column names

Comment: My code does refer to the column by name.

Comment: Hi Jos, Thanks for the reply and sorry if my question is not clear enough but need to refer   the "Capital" column while iterating over "Country" column databodyrange because there are more than one column to update.

Comment: You need to clarify why you need to iterate over the Country column. "because there are more than one column to update" doesn't make sense to me. If there are several columns to update then they can each be referred to by their name - I don't see any need to reference the Country column at all, unless there's some condition that has to be met in that column which you haven't told us about.

Comment: Hi Jos :) I have two sheets, one is lookup (normal range) and other is to change (table). Now, for each row in the update table, if "Country", "Location" and "Weather" match the values in the lookup table, I update a column in the update table. Now to do this, I am iterating over "Country" column and accessing "Location" & "Weather" values by offset relative to the "Country" column (for each). The problem is that the relative locations of "Location" and "Weather" might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If [Your Test] Then
            .ListColumns("Capital").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "Changed"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Change [Your Test] as required, for example:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    For i = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If .ListColumns("Country").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "A" Then
            .ListColumns("Capital").DataBodyRange(i).Value = "Changed"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thankyou, that solved it. Sometimes the iteration is over a filtered range so in that case how to put the index on SpecialCells?   DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: Rather than trying to account for whether a given row is filtered or not, preferable to add a new condition to the loop, equivalent to the condition which is being used for the filter.